# Easy conversion from instance of inherited class

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance

I have two classes, one which inherits the other, for example:-

```
public class A
{
    public string AA { get; set; }
    public double AB { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class B : A
{
    public double? BA { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I know that if I have an instance of object B, I can cast that as type A, but I have an instance of A that I want to instantiate as a type B object.  I know I could put a constructor in B's class which copies all the property values over, but the base class, A, has quite a few properties and may well have more added, so I'm worried about missing one or forgetting to add it in to B's constructor when I add it to A.  Is there an easy way of doing this, please?

-------Edit------

Thanks folks, not my use-case unfortunately, it's a question a mate's fired at me.  As far as I'm aware there are issues and he can't change the base class.  As I understand it, the base class is one that hooks into a database call, he then wants to grab that data and add some extra properties for an admin editing screen which his code will then use to update the base data object's properties.  My first reaction was to have the base object as a property of his object, but there's a reason it's significantly easier for him to have it "flattened" with the tools he's using.  I didn't *think* there was a way of doing this, but I thought I'd check in case I was missing something - I thought it would be easier to just ask the basic question, rather than include the background, which would probably just raise more questions and muddy the water (AFAIK he's suffering from "circumstances beyond his control", with this).

Comment: Well, it's not something you should be doing all that often in the first place.  It's a sign of an underlying design issue in most cases.  Chances are you'd be better off using composition rather than inheritance.  Class B should have a field of type A, rather than inheriting it.

Comment: What is the actual, real use case here?  This is typically a sign that you need to rethink the design.  There's probably a better fundamental approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know I could put a constructor in B's class which copies all the property values over, but the base class, A, has quite a few properties and may well have more added, so I'm worried about missing one or forgetting to add it in to B's constructor when I add it to A. Is there an easy way of doing this, please?

Typically, this is a sign of a design flaw.  I would rethink your design *first*, and determine whether this is truly necessary, or if there is another approach you can use here.  That being said...

There is no easy way to do this.  If you need a `B` instance to be created from your `A` instance, you'll really need to copy the values over to the new instance.

A better option, however, would potentially be to add a (potentially `protected`) constructor to `A` that sets all of these properties, given another `A` instance.  `B` could then use this to create itself, which at least keeps the requirements for matching all of the properties within the class that defines them.  This should make it easier to maintain this over time.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the other remarks, you're better off using a different design, such as composition instead of inheritance.

Composition, shown below, allows you to modify class A without requiring any changes to class B.

```
    public class B
    {
        // Constructor
        public B(A A) { this.A = A; }

        // Class A as a read-only property
        public A A { get; private set; }

        // Other properties of class B
        public double? BA { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Reverse Polymorphism is not supported in c#.

Answer (score 0):

As Reed Copsey said, this is typically a sign of a design flaw. I would re-work the class diagram if you need something like this to work. It sounds like some sort of mistake was made in the inheritance architecture somewhere.

If all you need is for both child and parent to implement common methods so that when either of the objects is passed to some function it can operate on some common methods on the passed-in object, then just have the two of them implement the same interface (polymorphism), or type the function parameter as the base class and make sure the methods exist on the base class.